# Java/Xml/Android - Calling random Strings from .XML String file in the Java

Tags: java, android, xml, string

I'm currently developing android **quiz app** and I implemented the "reset" button that resets the questions and randomize them, but **I'm having trouble with calling the random Strings from .xml file in MainActivity.java.**

I have all of my questions listed in the Strings.xml file like this, in order to make them easy to translate:

```
<string name="q1">The reactor at the site of the Chernobyl nuclear disaster is now in which country?</string>
<string name="a1">A. Slovakia</string>
<string name="b1">B. Ukraine</string>
<string name="c1">C. Hungary</string>
<string name="d1">D. Russia</string>
<string name="q1answer">B</string>
```

All of the questions are listed in that file like *q1, q2, q3,* and the same goes for ABCD answers: *a1, b1, c1, d1; a2, b2, c2, d2*, and so on.

There are many questions, but button chooses only 5 of them and displays them on the screen. The **problem is that I just can't access the Strings if I want to use an integer generated by randomizer to find them in .xml**:

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

        // I managed to get the identifier of the TextView with the for loop like that (TextViews for questios are listed q1q, q2q, q3q, q4q, q5q):
        // I would like to do the same thing down there with Strings.
        TextView question = (TextView) findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("q" + i + "q", "id", this.getPackageName()));

        // randomQuestion is the number of the question in random number generator from different method.
        randomQuestion = randomizeNumbers();

        // And here I'm stuck, this will show "q1-randomNumber" instead of the real question, 
        // because it does not see it as an ID. I tried various different solutions, but nothing works.
        question.setText("q" + randomQuestion);

        // I left the most silly approach to show what I mean.
    }
```

**What can I do to make the computer distinguish the name of the String? So it displays the real question instead of "q1" "q6" "q17"?**

Thank you for help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access strings from the string.xml file by using the getIdentifier() utility.

```
  private String getStringByName(String name) {
  int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(name, "string", getPackageName());
  return getString(resId);
}
```

It would be a lot easier if you also tried another approach entirely and create a Problem class which would look something like :

```
public class Problem(){
int ID;
String question;
String answer1; String answer2; //..and so on
String answerCorrect;

public class Problem(int ID, String question, ...){
this.question= question;
... 
}
}
```

And than, create and ArrayList = new ArrayList<>(); and populate it with your questions. Than, you would have the ability to access them by their ID / position in array, search them by name and so on. In the future, you can use this model to request the list of problems from a server too.

Comment: Sadly I was told to use .xml so it is easier for translators later on, BUT the first reply solved the problem :).

            int answer = getResources().getIdentifier("q"+randomQuestion, "string", this.getPackageName());

Works perfectly, earlier I did not change "id" to "string". Thanks mate!

Comment: Glad it helped ! Tried to give a little extra :D feel free to "up" the answer if it solved the problem. Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

```
question.setText("q" + randomQuestion);
```

In here, your parameter is inferred as a string since you pass `"q"`, so it will display `"q-randomNumber"` as expected. I think what you want is to pass and actual ID to `setText`. To do this, you can do the same approach you did to find the question textview ID using "string" instead of "id".

Comment: Thats true, earlier I did not change "id" to "string". Now it works perfectly fine, cheers! 
            int answer = getResources().getIdentifier("q"+randomQuestion, "string", this.getPackageName());

Comment: do you mind if i ask you to mark this as a correct answer if it helped you? It would be a great deal for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

In the MainActivity or in a function :

```
Resources res = getResources();

        myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.YOURXMLFILE);

        String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];
// WE GET THE TEXTVIEW
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView15);
        tv.setText(q);
// WE SET THE TEXTVIEW WITH A RANDOM QUESTION
```

And declare :

```
private String[] myString;
private static final Random rgenerator = new Random();
private TextView tv;
```